# Gmail SMTP блокирует отправку сообщений сайтом

Tags: php, wordpress, smtp

Настроил плагин на WordPress для отправки сообщений пользователям, но когда я пытаюсь отправить тестовый e-mail мне приходит сообщение такого типа:

> Заблокирована попытка входа в аккаунт  Здравствуйте! Кто-то только что
>   пытался войти в аккаунт имя@gmail.com через небезопасное приложение.

Я начитался на [офф сайте](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=ru) про разные проблемы с этим и что нужен платный аккаунт Google Apps, но я никак не пойму что на самом деле правда, не подскажете что делать?

Благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой.

[Ссылка на решение.](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=ru)

Смысл в том, что нужно отключить проверку "надежности" у себя в аккаунте.
И от меня вопрос: Может кто-то знает как сделать себя надежным для google?

Comment: Я уже и забыл об этой теме :) Не хочу советовать то чего не знаю, но я скажу что думаю что это либо платные функции либо нужна подписка разработчика.. Но к чему все эти сложности..

Comment: Внутри сервиса нужно реализовать что-то типа почтового сервиса (с возможностью получать и отправлять письма). И, думаю, клиентов будет отпугивать, если будет приходить такое письмо на email,  что ресурс ненадежен.

Answer (score 1):

1. Открываем gmail.
2. Тыкаем на аватарку справа и выбираем "Управление аккаунтом Google".
3. Раздел "Безопасность" --> "Ненадежные приложения, у которых есть доступ к аккаунту".
4. Тыкаем "Открыть доступ(не рекомендуется)" и перемещаем ползунок "Небезопасные приложения заблокированы" вправо, разрешая сие действие.

Готово.